# viewpager is not showing any fragment

Tags: android

I have created two fragments in my app. I want to use these fragments in viewpager. This is my CustomAdapter for Viewpager:

```
public class CustomSwipeAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public CustomSwipeAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                return new fragmentComment();

            case 1:
                return new fragment_Rating();

            default:
                return new fragmentComment();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

And this is my Viewpager:

```
pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
FragmentActivity fm=new FragmentActivity();
CustomSwipeAdapter adapter=new CustomSwipeAdapter(fm.getSupportFragmentManager());
pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But when i run my app,nothing is shown in viewpager.
Can Anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot

> adapter.addFragment(new fragmentComment(), "FragmentComment");
>   adapter.addFragment(new fragment_Rating(), "FragmentRating");

Comment: But I have passed Arraylist of fragments in adapter.

Comment: If you have passed an arraylist you must return in below manner getItem()
return mFragmentList.get(position);

Comment: Now I have changed my getItem method with this                                 
 return this.fragments.get(position);

Comment: But nothing changed

Comment: Also you should use FragmentPagerAdapter and not FragmentStatePagerAdapter